# How to retrieve list of files in MSIX package with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, uwp, appx, msix

I have a `msix` package (I have `msix` file and `appxsym` file) and I want to retrieve list of files inside of `msix` package with PowerShell programmatically.

I can do this with [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/tool-overview), But I want to do it with PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: MSIX is just ZIP file format so you could use .NET `ZipArchive` class to get file info. File names appear to be URL-encoded.

Comment: What exactly is the end purpose? What are you trying to achieve with the list of files from the package?

The list of files from the package is included in the AppxBlockmap.xml manifest from the package. So if you manage to extract the archive using the ZipArchive class as suggested above you just need to parse the blockmap manifest to get the full list, instead of actually indexing the contents of the packages.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache I want to write script that extract list of files and check with desired list in CI to ensure packaging is correct behavior.